# How to restart an executable process as a domain administrator automatically using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, basic

I need some help. All the variables are below. Hopefully someone can help shed light on this issue.

#### Environment:

I have proprietary processing software running on a [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) VM box running on a Windows Domain.

Basically this software is an executable, and it is run manually from a Domain account (logged in and manually open the a shortcut on the desktop)

#### Issue/Objective:

This software runs as a command prompt and every so often (a couple of days) it turns off without warning. We get an alert via [Nagios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) monitoring and [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) in and start the process again. This server is in production and this is not practical. We are trying to use a script that checks for the process and starts it if it's not running.

#### Attempted solutions - We’ve tried quite a few things and just for the record:

- We converted this process into a Windows service and because of the nature of the software it cannot run as a service.
- We tried to use Nagios scripts to restart the service, BUT keyword service this software cannot run as a service, so that’s not an option.
- We tried a program called [ReStartMe](http://bkprograms.weebly.com/restartme.html). It didn't work for us; it crashed the software.

#### Most promising solution:

We found a restart application script online, and it does restart the application. However, the application starts improperly, stalls, shuts down, and restarts again continuously.

We think this happens because the application starts in a shell and may not have the proper user permissions to run the executable. It is not equivalent to an authenticated user opening on the desktop.

The code for this script is pasted below. We are hoping someone can help shed some light on this for us. Getting this resolved would save lots of headaches for us.

#### Restart program script:

```
set Service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Name of the EXE file we want to watch
sEXEName = "processing.exe"

'Path of the folder it is in (Don't forget the trailing \)
sApplicationPath = "C:\process\"

'Loop until the system is shutdown or user logs out
while true
    bRunning = false

    'Look for our application. Set the flag bRunning = true
    'If we see that it is running

    for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
        if Process.Name = sEXEName then
            bRunning=true
        End If
    next

    'Is our application running?

    if (not bRunning) then

        'No it is not, launch it
        Shell.Run Chr(34) & sApplicationPath & sEXEName & Chr(34)
    end if

    'Sleep a while so we do not hog the CPU
    WScript.Sleep(2000)
wend
```

Comment: If the authenticated user is running the script the same way he or she would run the application, then it isn't a permissions problem.  Could be to do with the current directory.  Try having the script launch the shortcut to the application (the same one you would use to launch it by hand) rather than the executable itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `Run`:

```
If Not bRunning Then
  Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  app.ShellExecute Chr(34) & sApplicationPath & sEXEName & Chr(34), , _
                   sApplicationPath, , 1
End If
```

I'd probably try a batch script first, though. `start /wait processing.exe` should launch the application and wait for it to terminate. If that works (doesn't for some applications), you could create a batch script like this:

```
@echo off

cd C:\process

:LOOP
start "" /wait processing.exe
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul 2>&1
goto LOOP
```

and create a shortcut to that batch script with the "run as admin" flag set in the user's startup folder. That way the program should automatically start with elevated privileges and should be automatically re-started whenever it crashes. The `ping` is just for adding a short delay before starting over to give the system some time to clean up after the process crashed.

Comment: Ansgar, thank you so much for your prompt response, I've added your first piece of Code and agree that creating a batch file and setting is as a start up time is the way to go with this script.

Comment: Ansgar, thank you so much for your prompt response, I've added your first piece of Code and agree that creating a batch file and setting is as a start up item is the way to go with this script, and I will do that once the script is working properly
I think you are definitely helping us in the right direction however when I run the script with your modifications then shut down the process the following occurs:

Comment: 1. This window on the link below appears twice: http://blogs.technet.com/blogfiles/kevinholman/WindowsLiveWriter/WheredidmyRunAsgo_D3DA/image_thumb.png

2. If I choose to run as "Current User" and deselect "Run this program with restricted access" the process restarts perfectly.

3. As I said the Run As opens twice and repeating the above step for the second run as window opens an unnecessary second instance of the program which is unnecessary. Im not sure why this happens.

Comment: As of now it seems the only issues with your suggested modification to the script are the following:
1. I think it tries to run the program twice as it opens two "run as" windows, it should only run once.
2.  The "run as" window requires manual input and we are aiming to make this an automated action, so if there is some way to bypass this or authenticate "run as" prompt and allow the program to run unrestricted, automatically within the scrip that would be great.

Angsar, thank you again for your help on this it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @virtual020: Sorry, I didn't realize that you're running this on Windows Server 2003. Try without the `"runas"` verb (see updated answer).